# Power BI - When I add date field to a table, power BI adds the date hierarchy instead of just the date

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have one table in Power BI data model.

[image]

In report view, I have created a table and added Date field to the table. I just want the date to appear as 2023-01-01. Instead, the only option I have is to add it as hierarchy and no way to add date as a field.

[image]

How I can just display the date?